# Magento Ajax from Module

Tags: php, ajax, magento, module

I am new to magento module development. I want  to request ajax call from magento backend.. Here I made module... Here is the screenshot
[image]

I have fields like this:

```
<tpropay translate="label" module="tpropay">
                <label>Tpro3</label>
                <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                <comment><![CDATA[ 
                <button class="scalable" onclick="return check(); ">Sync Products Now</button>  ]]></comment>

<fields>
 <active translate="label">
   <label>Enabled</label>
   <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
   <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
   <sort_order>1</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
 </active>
</fields>
</tpropay>
```

Now I want ajax call when user click on button? Confused about how to include javascript and send ajax call... Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your controller, to which you are going to call ajax then put your JavaScript in a file and add that js file by layout xml like below

`<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>folder/ajax.js</script></action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>`

Hope that helps

Comment: issue is that.. how can I upload this to different projects... because javascript files will be out of the module directory